# To select value from ajax dropdown elements having same classname using Selenium

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a particular value from two Ajax drop down fields. But both the ajax value container is having same classname 'ac_results'. So only the value from the first ajax dropdown field is getting selected and its not identifying the second ajax dropdown value. Please help me with this regard.
HTML code:

```html
 <div class="ac_results" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 150px; top: 225px; left: 489.317px;">

    <ul style="max-height: 180px; overflow: auto;">

        <li class="ac_even"></li>
        <li class="ac_odd"></li>
        <li class="ac_even"></li>
        <li class="ac_odd"></li>
        <li class="ac_even"></li>
        <li class="ac_odd"></li>
        <li class="ac_even"></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div class="ac_results" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 150px; top: 225px; left: 781.733px;">

    <ul style="max-height: 180px; overflow: auto;">

        <li class="ac_even"></li>
        <li class="ac_odd"></li>
        <li class="ac_even"></li>
        <li class="ac_odd"></li>
    </ul>
```

Code:

```html
//get the from field
  WebElement fromCity = driver.findElement(By.id("txtStationFrom"));
  
  //Enter the value into the from city field
  fromCity.sendKeys("ban");
  
  //wait for some time
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  
  //get the ajax container having values
  WebElement ajaxContainer1 = driver.findElement(By.className("ac_results"));
  
  WebElement ajaxHolder1 = ajaxContainer1.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
  
  //Values in the container
  List<WebElement> ajaxValues1 = ajaxHolder1.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
  
  for (WebElement value1 : ajaxValues1) {
   if(value1.getText().equals("BANGALORE CY JN- SBC")){
    value1.click();
    break;
   }
  }
  
  //Get the to city field
  WebElement toCity = driver.findElement(By.id("txtStationTo"));
  
  //pass the value to the field  
  toCity.sendKeys("sub");
  
  //Wait for some time
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  
  //get the container of the ajax toCity
  
  WebElement ajaxContainer2 = driver.findElement(By.className("ac_results"));
  
  WebElement ajaxHolder2 = ajaxContainer2.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
  
  List<WebElement> ajaxValues2 = ajaxHolder2.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
  
  for (WebElement value2 : ajaxValues2) {
   
   if(value2.getText().equals("SUBRAHMANYA ROAD- SBHR")){
    value2.click();
    break;
   }  
  }
```

Comment: Did you try using xpath?

Comment: @HelpingHands No i did not use xpath.

Comment: Then you should try.

Comment: HTML you have shared is of not actual dropdown, you might be using some plugin/framework which generated dropdown out of it.

Comment: @HelpingHands: I tried xpath, but getting "NoSuchElementException" error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
//div[@class='ac_results'][0] // For first Drop Down
//div[@class='ac_results'][1] // For second Drop Down

or
List<WebElement> dropDowns = driver.findElements(By.className('ac_results'));
WebElement dropDownOne = dropDowns.get(0); // perform further action using this WebElement
WebElement dropDownTwo = dropDowns.get(1); // Second drop down
```

Comment: I tried both the solutions, getting "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException" while using xpath solution. And getting "IndexOutOfBound" Exception for the second Solution. Please help me with this.

Comment: @ChetanKumarT: Try it with an explicit wait.

Comment: @ManaliJ: Getting "NoSuchElementException" for the xpath " //div[@class='ac_results'][0] " so i think explicit wait does'nt work.

Comment: @ChetanKumarT Seems like you are doing something wrong there. Did you try to print size of `dropDowns`, if it is 0. Then you did not share code correctly and if it is 1 then recheck second drop down whether that is visible/enable or not.  If it is 2 then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried, but not getting web elements list

Its google search tab Test script where just search for random thing : "ran"
my code :

```
@Test
enter code herepublic void checkDropDownofSearchBox(){
    int i = 0;
    WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.className("sbdd_a"));
    WebElement ajaxHolder1 = dropDown.findElement(By.className("sbdd_b"));

    List<WebElement> ajaxValues1 = ajaxHolder1.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    for (WebElement value1 : ajaxValues1) {
        System.out.println(value1.getText());
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: HTML Code : HTML :

<div>
<div class="sbdd_b" style="">
<div class="sbsb_a">
<ul class="sbsb_b" role="listbox">
<li class="sbsb_c gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
<li class="sbsb_c gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
<li class="sbsb_c gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
<li class="sbsb_c gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
</ul>
</div>
</div>